# change color of text surrounded by quotes or custom

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a weird case where I need to search my navigation link titles and change specific colors based on their mark up.

For reasons beyond my control, within the CMS tool I am using, I have a single input field for the title of the nav item.

Lets say, for this example, its "Why choose Stack Overflow?"

I'd like to implement a javascript hook that can change the color of "Why choose" and leave "Stack Overflow?" to its normal css styling.

I was thinking of introducing something similar to forum codes, like, `"*Why choose* Stack Overflow?"`

Now, I could use javascript to search for * and replace with `<div class='uniquecss'>`

I saw jquery's [name$] but am too unfamiliar with it to really understand how to get it working.

Here is some HTML to help with this example:

```
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><div class='stext'>IT'S YOUR RIGHT TO</div>BREATHE RIGHT</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#"><div class='stext'>IT'S YOUR RIGHT TO</div>BREATHE RIGHT</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><div class='stext'>THE BENEFITS OF</div>BREATHING RIGHT</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><div class='stext'>HOW BREATHE RIGHT</div>WORKS</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><div class='stext'>BREATHE RIGHT</div>PRODUCTS</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li><a href="#"><div class='stext'>THE BENEFITS OF</div>BREATHING RIGHT</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><div class='stext'>HOW BREATHE RIGHT</div>WORKS</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#"><div class='stext'>IT'S YOUR RIGHT TO</div>BREATHE RIGHT</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><div class='stext'>THE BENEFITS OF</div>BREATHING RIGHT</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><div class='stext'>HOW BREATHE RIGHT</div>WORKS</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><div class='stext'>BREATHE RIGHT</div>PRODUCTS</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"><div class='stext'>BREATHE RIGHT</div>PRODUCTS</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

This is essentially how I want it to look.  I'd like to make it fairly robust in the sense that it will scan for the first `*` add `<div class='stext'>` then in the next `*` add `</div>`

I could probably get it working assuming I learn what the right jquery / javascript to use for this task would be.

Any other suggestions would be great too! Thanks

(again, because of the CMS tool we are using, I can't do any other edits to the link title, so this is the best solution I could come up with)

Comment: Look up bbcode, or more importantly a javascript bcode parser. Simple bit of regex and you can specify your own tags and what to transform them into inside the regex replacement pattern

Comment: I'm not sure why you need javascript to accomplish this - do you not have control over the CSS? Or is the HTML in the example only a representation of how you think it would look after applying the javascript?

Comment: @jake the html provided was only an example.  Essentially what i would prefer it look like after JS went through it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$("a").each(function() {
  this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace(
               /\*([^\*]+)\*/g, 
               '<div class="stext">$1</div>');
});
```

(See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KRWyb/))

Comment: This answer is not quite efficient since  When you have `<a href="#">Some *div text* and *link* text</a>` even `...and...` will be highlighted